# How can I change the "Commit All" button of Team Explorer tab

Tags: git, synchronization, visual-studio-2017, commit, team-explorer

[Team Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqxHA.png)

Is that possible to change default button-"Commit All" to "Commit All and Sync"
?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is currently no way to change the commit button's default behavior from "Commit All" to one of the other options.  We are monitoring user feedback to see if this is an enhancement we should make in the future.

Comment: Normally a git user commits often and pushes changes when they need to be shared. Under normal conditions pushing every time you commit doesn't really make sense in my opinion. It would, however, be useful when working on a project alone for example.